# f# function not recognized as parameter

Tags: f#, system.reactive, agent

Please unwrap these type signatures to help me understand why this doesn't work.
Then, if you have a solution, that would be great too.

I have this code and the agent.Post command has the signature `Observer.Create<'T>(onNext: Action<'T>) : IObserver<'T>`

```
let reservatinoRequestObserver = Observer.Create agent.Post
interface IHttpControllerActivator with
```

To my knowledge, this means that `Observer.Create` should take an Action with a single generic parameter and then return an IObserver.

Now the definition of Post is `member MailboxProcessor.Post : message:'Msg ->unit`

So... Post is a method, no?  It is a method that takes a single parameter no?  And it returns void no?  So shouldn't it be a candidate for Observer.Create?  Isn't that the exact specification of Action<'T>?

Well, somethings up, I get **This function takes too many arguments, or is used in a context where a function is not expected**:
[image]

Help me out... I freely admit I suck at F#

Comment: it is a common trap with interop - does not mean that you suck at all! - But you could help us  lot if you would not only post screenshots - usually copy&pasteable code is a good idea ;)

Comment: I recognise this code! :) I've recently gone through [Mark Seeman's excellent FSharp Functional Architecture](http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/functional-architecture-fsharp) course too.. I uploaded all the code I wrote for this to github. It's a VS2013 project modified to use Owin+Katana WebApi. Check the git tags for the key stages of in-memory, file and azure persistence alternatives. It's all [here](https://github.com/james-world/ploehfsharparchitecture). Hope it helps! It should all just "work". I can run the Azure stuff against the local emulator as well as publish to Azure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `agent.Post` returns `unit`, which is a different thing from `void`. F# will usually convert back and forth between `void` and `unit` for you, but they are not the same thing.

Second, F# functions do not implicitly convert to .NET delegates. 
But there are some ways to do it:

#### You can explicitly create the delegate using its constructor:

```
let o = Observer.Create (new Action<_>( agent.Post ))
```

#### Lambdas are nicely wrapped too

```
let o = Observer.Create (fun msg -> agent.Post msg)
```

#### Use F# Rx-wrappers

Also there are a [couple of F# wrappers/interop for Rx on nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=fsharp+rx) - just have a look, I think any will do

Comment: this is not 100% right - I allowed myself to edit your answer a bit - I hope you don't mind - if you do just revert the changes (if you have not enough rep let me know and I'll do it)

Comment: Shouldn't `Observer.Create (Action agent.Post)` do for the first way? It looks a bit noisy like this.

Comment: It should do, only add generic argument: `Observer.Create (Action<_> agent.Post)`. The use of constructors as functions is a new feature in F# 4.0, and I didn't know what version you were using, so I wanted to be safe.

Comment: You can leave out the parentheses for constructor calls with only one parameter in F# 3 as well; it doesn't see it as a function call because of that.